# Readfile() does not successfully download file

Tags: php, web, download, readfile

I've created a small snippet of code to test out the functionality of readfile(), which I would like to use for the development of my larger-scale project. As a test, this is the code that I wrote:

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form method="post">
    
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit1"><br/><br/>
    
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["Submit1"]))
        {
            $filetry = 'Cat.jpg';
    
            if (file_exists($filetry)){
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filetry).'"');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length'.filesize($filetry));
                readfile($filetry);
                exit;
            } 
    
        }
        ?>
    
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've used the PHP manual from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php to help me construct the code, but I still have no idea why it cannot successfully download the image
[and gives me a "Could not load image error".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1APF.png) . I've read that larger images may have trouble with the download, but this pic is only around 900KB. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

`readfile()` is likely to be working correctly, but the problem is that you've output several bits of HTML before you output the file content. That HTML ends up in the final downloaded output together with the data from `readfile()`. This will make the resulting downloaded content invalid as a JPEG.

To solve it, simply move the

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit1"])) {
...
}
```

block *before* any other output on your page. (Since it `exit`s at the end of the block that'll ensure no other subsequent content is downloaded as part of the file.)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your speedy response! I've moved my block text before the HTML, and I'm seeing some progress but it's not completely successful. The image can now be downloaded, but it seems to only show a few pixelated rows but the rest is greyed out: https://imgur.com/a/ClZSuAh. Does this have to do with the file stream?

Comment: Not sure. You seem to be viewing it in some sort of image gallery, it's hard to tell from the picture. If you download it and just open in a regular windows image viewer or something, does it look ok? Have you verified that the original on the server is ok?

Comment: Yes, I'm opening this on a regular image viewer, its the one that I use that comes built-in with my Linux OS. The original image that I've downloaded looks fine: https://imgur.com/a/hhNj99u but only after it is downloaded, it shows me a greyed out image like the previous example. I've tested it on another image as well and it still shows the same result.

Comment: Hm. It's a bit weird. Make sure there's absolutely no other content such as whitespace or hidden characters which could be leaking into the downloaded data.